# Cleaning up Html5 pages with Java: Is it possible?

Tags: java, html, java-7, jtidy

I need to clean up Html5 pages inside my Java project.

So I need a Java library, or a command line program working both on Linux and Windows.

JTidy doesn't work well (I tested it).
HTML Tidy for HTML5 is a C++ Library and it's command line version works only on Linux.

Do you know if Validator.nu HTML Parser also cleans up (I didn't find any information about it)?

Have you any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you understand by "cleaning"? Removing bad or potentially dangerous tags? Reformatting? Validating HTML5-correctness?

Comment: I mean "have a well-formed version of the input webpage".

Comment: Then you want to parse and re-output, and not "clean". The parser will alert you on problems.

Comment: You're right. Parse() method transform webpages in a well-formed version. Thanks! :)

Comment: ¿accept my answer, perhaps? (click on the check-mark next to the answer, and/or upvote by clicking the upwards-triangle)

Comment: Checked the answer, but i can't vote (I need a better reputation)

Comment: No. It's not possible. There's no possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). Well supported, no native components (should run everywhere Java does), free-but-very-liberal license. Also, supports HTML5

Comment: I tried to use Jsoup and the clean() method, but i didn't understand if I have to add manually ALL the Html5 tags to the WhiteList object(GULP!), or there's another way to clean the page...

Comment: Depends on your requirements (see comment above). You may have enough with just tweaking the default Whitelist.relaxed(), for example. It covers most simple HTML.

Comment: The "relaxed" works fine for the body tags, but i didn't figure out how to add the head tags...